# How can i check a ALAsset is a Image .How can i seperate image(.png) files from ALAssetGroup

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios4

How can i check a ALAsset is a  Image? How can i seperate image(.png) files from ALAssetGroup.can i able to retrieve only the image(.png) files from iphone Photo libaray ?

Answer (score 15):

First of all you need to enumerate the whole AssetGroup
Then check every asset for 2 things:

1) For checking if the Asset is an image, query

```
[[asset valueForProperty:@"ALAssetPropertyType"] isEqualToString:@"ALAssetTypePhoto"]
```

2) if 1) is true then continue the check, if it is a PNG like this:

```
[[[asset defaultRepresentation] UTI] isEqualToString:@"public.png"]
```

Answer (score 5):

Without using NSString:

`[[asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyType] isEqual:ALAssetTypeVideo]`